# Remove all of a specific value from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

i have an array called acceptedTermsPoints(), and it is outputting 0,3,3,0,0 which is fine. What i need is a way to remove all of the values equal to 0, so that the array is equal to 3, 3

I don't have any code but please use acceptedTermsPoints() in the example. Thanks! Any help is appreciated

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/nR2ds/

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter`

```
var newArray = acceptedTermsPoints().filter(e => e != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var acceptedTermsPoints = [0,3,3,0,0];

function isGreaterThanZero(value) {
  return value > 0;
}
var NewacceptedTermsPoints = acceptedTermsPoints.filter(isGreaterThanZero);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a functional approach:

```
function notEquals(n) {
  return function (el) {
    return el !== n;
  }
}

function removeZeros(arr) {
  return arr.filter(notEquals(0));
}

removeZeros(acceptedTermsPoints()); // [3, 3]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/h5vs6dxg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) as callback. This filters all values not like `0` or other falsy values.

```js
var array = [0, 3, 3, 0, 0],
    result = array.filter(Boolean);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```